# Duplicate values not returning correct cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

[Duplicate Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEG2L.png)

I have this image of what is happening when sorting the top scores from the largest to the lowest. The issue is that when two teams have the same score (Team 1 and Team 2 in the image) it shows only Team 1 in the Top Scores column.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you look at the Top Teams column, these are entered with the =INDEX($B$1:$B$10,MATCH(D3,C:C,0)) (First column is the B1:B10 where D is the Top Scores column which is taken from the C column using the Large() Excel function. So Team #3 has the highest score which is well identified with the Large() function but when the scores are identical, the Large function doesn't show that Team #2 has the same score and therefore just shows Team #1 twice. I hope that is more clear. Thanks.

Comment: So is there anybody that understands the issue I have posted or is there something else I would have to clarify? Thank you for your time and understanding.